# Connect to SVN repo in eclipse - how?

Tags: svn, eclipse

Running OS X 10.6, Eclipse Helios. How to set up a new PHP project with SVN integration? I am following a guide which appears a little old.  These instructions does not work for the following reasons. SVN is not an option.

1. Click File -> New -> Project… This will open a new dialog window.
2. Select SVN -> Checkout Projects From SVN.

My Eclipse has other options, no SVN folder I'm afraid. I found a picture wich has the folder the guide is refeering to:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Installing Subclipse

In order to use SVN in Eclipse, you need a SVN plug in, preferably [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/). Here's the [installation guide](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess;jsessionid=6E5744168903E82710CBA3D622FE6192?pageID=p4wYuA).

- Go to *Help → Install new Software*. Locate the "Add" button.
- Add a new remote site using the name "Subclipse" and the URL `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x`
- Then, select all packages and click *Next*.

[image]

- Click through the dialog. Accept the terms of service and the warning that you install unsigned software.
- Restart Eclipse when prompted so.

Now you should have SVN integration. You can either manually add SVN repositories or define them as you go. Mostly you want to share an existing project to a new SVN repository. This is how to do that.

#### Manually adding repos

- Go to *Window → Open Perspective → Other...*.
- Select "SVN Repository Exploring"
- In the left panel, right-click and select *New*. Here you can add your remote repositories.

Once you have added a repository, you can share a project on it.

#### Checking out from an existing repo

If you already have a project in SVN, you can also checkout the existing project over the SVN Explorer, if that is what you want to do.

- Right-click the repository
- Click *Checkout*
- Use "Check out as a project in workspace"
- Click *Finish*

#### Defining a new repo as you go

- In the main perspective, right-click the project and select *Team*
- This will be the main menu for all SVN actions (Committing, Branching, etc.)
- First, select *Share* and work through the menu, specifying your remote repository